# SQL syntax error (with procedural insert)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

i need to execute two queries for different table. i have tested code blow:

```
$insert= $mysqli->query("BEGIN;INSERT INTO 
patient(patient_firstName,patient_familyName,patient_age,patient_emailAddress, patient_physicalAddress, 
patient_mobile,date_of_register,uusernamee,ppasswordd) 
values('1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1');insert into 
patient_requests(patient_id,subject,description)values('222','22222','22222'); Commit; ") ;
```

and here is the error it shows:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO patient(patient_firstName, patient_familyName,
>   patient_age, patient_' at line 1()

where do i wrong?

thanks in advance..!

Comment: `$mysqli->query` accepts only one query at a time. And `BEGIN;` is one. That is why the error points out what comes next: `INSERT INTO ...`

Comment: @juergend thanks, can u propose the alternative for mysqli>query or the code correction?

Comment: Change your `query` to `multi_query` or break it into multiple queries manually.

Comment: Split it into three queries:
1.) `BEGIN;`
2.) `INSERT INTO ... values( .... );`
3.) `COMMIT;`

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata thanks for answer. i'm afraid i can't, cuz i'm using it in a private function! (can it be a problem? cuz i face with errors when i use multiple query when use in private function)

Comment: @TobiasF. it worked. thanks for your time & sharing!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform multiple `INSERT` in single DB transaction, you can try this way:

```
// begin DB transaction
$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);

// multiple inserts queries
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ....");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ....");

$mysqli->commit();
```